# Overlay with text on a polygon marked area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a List of six Items which are placed in two rows. Now I would like to create an overlay effect as soon as you hover over one item. The more Tricky part would be I wand to be able to place some text on the overlay which should be positioned on the biggest available part of that overlay. I believe I have to have a class for each item just like the polygons with different positioning.

**My Problem: I can't get the overlay done.** Right now the polygon on hover are on the content element. I would like to have that on an overlay being on top of the content element so it hides the other elements and set text to it.

```js
var contentElement = document.querySelectorAll("div.content");
var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li");
liElements.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
    if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'One' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polyone");
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Two' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polytwo");
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Three' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polythree");
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Four' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polyfour");
    }  else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Five' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polyfive");
    }  else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Six' ){
        contentElement[0].classList.remove("polysix");
    } 
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
    if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'One' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polyone') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polyone");
        }
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Two' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polytwo') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polytwo");
        }
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Three' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polythree') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polythree");
        }
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Four' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polyfour') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polyfour");
        }
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Five' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polyfive') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polyfive");
        }
    } else if( item.querySelector('div.text span').innerHTML === 'Six' ){
        if ( !contentElement[0].classList.contains('polysix') ) {
            contentElement[0].classList.add("polysix");
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.cutoff {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}
div.cutoff:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  
  background-color: white;
  /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 80%, 0 20%); */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%);
}
div.cutoff:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  
  background-color: white;
  /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%); */
  clip-path: polygon(100% 80%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
div.content {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
div.polyone {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(33% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50%, 33% 50%);
}
div.polytwo {
  background-color: magenta;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 33% 0, 33% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
div.polythree {
  background-color: cyan;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 66% 0, 66% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}
div.polyfour {
  background-color: cyan;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 33% 100%, 33% 50%, 0 50%);
}
div.polyfive {
  background-color: magenta;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 66% 100%, 66% 50%, 33% 50%, 33% 100%, 0 100%);
}
div.polysix {
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 100%, 0 100%);
}
ul {
   list-style: none;
   padding-inline-start: 0;
}
ul.row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
li {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
li div.circle {
    background: lime;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
li i.icon {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
li div.text {
    margin: auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

li:hover {
    filter: brightness(40%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cutoff">
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
              <i class="icon">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
                </svg>
              </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>One</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
              </svg>
            </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>Two</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
              </svg>
            </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>Three</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
              </svg>
            </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>Four</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
              </svg>
            </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>Five</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0"/>
              </svg>
            </i>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <span>Six</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

[image: example3]

While imgur seems offline: https://ibb.co/rxNNRbM https://ibb.co/pvSjS6K https://ibb.co/zV2jrfc

**Update:**.
At least for prototype purposes this is what I wanted to achieve:

```js
        var mask = document.querySelector("div.content .mask");
        mask.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mask.className = 'mask'
        })
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
            if (e.target.nodeName === 'BODY') mask.className = 'mask'
        })
        var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        liElements.forEach((item, index) => {
            const { innerHTML } = item.querySelector('div.text span')
            item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
                if (innerHTML) {
                    mask.className = 'mask ' + innerHTML
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
        div.cutoff {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        div.cutoff:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;

            background-color: white;
            /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 80%, 0 20%); */
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%);
        }

        div.cutoff:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;

            background-color: white;
            /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%); */
            clip-path: polygon(100% 80%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        div.content {
            margin-top: 10%;
            margin-bottom: 10%;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .mask {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            font-size: 24px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .mask.One {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: red;
            clip-path: polygon(33% 13.5%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%, 0 50%, 33% 50%);
            padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 35%;
        }
        .mask.One:after {
            padding: 3rem;
            content: "One One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One OneOne One";
        }
        .mask.Two {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: magenta;
            clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 33% 13.5%, 33% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 7%, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%, 0 0);
            padding: 15% 1rem 1rem 1rem;
        }
        .mask.Two:after {
            content: "Two Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two TwoTwo Two";
        }

        .mask.Three {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: cyan;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 66% 0, 66% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
        }

        .mask.Four {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: cyan;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 33% 100%, 33% 50%, 0 50%);
        }

        .mask.Five {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: magenta;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 66% 100%, 66% 50%, 33% 50%, 33% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        .mask.Six {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: red;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding-inline-start: 0;
        }

        ul.row {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        li {
            padding: 1rem;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        li div.circle {
            background: lime;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        li i.icon {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }

        li div.text {
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        li:hover {
            filter: brightness(40%);
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            /* background-color: blue; */
        }
```

```html
<div class="cutoff">
        <div class="content">
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>One</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Two</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Three</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Four</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Five</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Six</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mask"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you actually want, from that flicker-y example and the ambiguous description. Needs a better explanation, IMHO. Maybe a mock-up screenshot of what it is supposed to actually look like when hovered would help.

Comment: Yeah I still have to work on the flickering as well. Anyway, I added 3 screenshot which hopeful explains my thoughts. PLease let me know if it's still unclear with the mockups.

Comment: I guess I would approach this with a different structure, and little to no JS at all. The overlay parts get put into the `li` elements, positioned so that they cover the whole area. When a `li` gets hovered, you give it a z-index so that it sits in front of everything else, and its overlay gets to sit "between" the hovered `li` and the rest, on the z-axis. The overlay itself gets `pointer-events: none`, so that the other, currently covered `li` can be hovered to switch to a different item.

Comment: Gonna have to think about that a little and will def try this out. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I add a div to create a mask with polygon but not to change the content div like you do,the polygon  may need  optimize but I think you can do it.

```html
<style>
        div.cutoff {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        div.cutoff:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;

            background-color: white;
            /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 80%, 0 20%); */
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%);
        }

        div.cutoff:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;

            background-color: white;
            /* -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 20%); */
            clip-path: polygon(100% 80%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        div.content {
            margin-top: 10%;
            margin-bottom: 10%;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .mask {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            font-size: 24px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .mask.One {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: red;
            clip-path: polygon(33% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50%, 33% 50%);
        }

        .mask.Two {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: magenta;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 33% 0, 33% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
        }

        .mask.Three {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: cyan;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 66% 0, 66% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
        }

        .mask.Four {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: cyan;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 33% 100%, 33% 50%, 0 50%);
        }

        .mask.Five {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: magenta;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 66% 100%, 66% 50%, 33% 50%, 33% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        .mask.Six {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: red;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 66% 50%, 66% 100%, 0 100%);
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding-inline-start: 0;
        }

        ul.row {
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        li {
            padding: 1rem;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        li div.circle {
            background: lime;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        li i.icon {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }

        li div.text {
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        li:hover {
            filter: brightness(40%);
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            /* background-color: blue; */
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="cutoff">
        <div class="content">
            <ul class="row">
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>One</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Two</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Three</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Four</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Five</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="col-4">
                    <div class="circle">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-airplane-engines-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 0c-.787 0-1.292.592-1.572 1.151A4.35 4.35 0 0 0 6 3v3.691l-2 1V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.191l-1.17.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 10.618V12a.5.5 0 0 0 .582.493l1.631-.272.313.937a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.405-1.214 2.21-.369.375 2.253-1.318 1.318A.5.5 0 0 0 5.5 16h5a.5.5 0 0 0 .354-.854l-1.318-1.318.375-2.253 2.21.369.405 1.214a.5.5 0 0 0 .948 0l.313-.937 1.63.272A.5.5 0 0 0 16 12v-1.382a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-.83-1.342L14 8.691V7.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.191l-2-1V3c0-.568-.14-1.271-.428-1.849C9.292.591 8.787 0 8 0" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span>Six</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mask"><span>This is a mask This is a mask This is a mask This is a mask</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var mask = document.querySelector("div.content .mask");
        mask.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mask.className = 'mask'
        })
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
            if (e.target.nodeName === 'BODY') mask.className = 'mask'
        })
        var liElements = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        liElements.forEach((item, index) => {
            const { innerHTML } = item.querySelector('div.text span')
            item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
                if (innerHTML) {
                    mask.className = 'mask ' + innerHTML
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: THis seems pretty much to be what I wanted. I'm working on it to see if I can fit this to meet my requirements and will accept the answer as soon as I'm done.